# Laravel - insert multiple rows with pivot table data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

1. Questions
2. Answers
3. question_answers

Question Model:

```
public function answer()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Answer::class);
    }
```

I created a page where I type a question and 4 answers, and I insert them to my database.

```
        $question = new Question;
        $question->title = $request->question_title;
        $question->save();

        $answers = $request->answers;
        $answer = Answer::insert($answers);
```

How I can insert the `question_answers` for each question too?

question_answers looks like this:

[image]

I couldn't find a clue how to do it with the `insert` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using many-to-many relationship, you should use [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method. For example:

```
$question = Question::create($request->question); // Save question.

$answersIds = [];
foreach ($request->answers as $answer) {
    $answersIds [] = Answer::create($answer)->id; // Save each answer.
}

$question->answers()->attach($answersIds); // Attach answers to the question.
```

Also you can't use `insert()` to bulk insert answers, because you need to get answer IDs to attach answers to the question.